# Does loops=1 mean caching in PostgreSQL's analyze output?

Tags: postgresql, explain

I've a slow query which I'd like to optimize. The query is very similar to the following sample:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;
CREATE TABLE test (i integer);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test2;
CREATE TABLE test2 (i integer);
INSERT INTO test2 VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO test2 VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO test2 VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO test2 VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO test2 VALUES (5);
INSERT INTO test2 VALUES (6);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test3;
CREATE TABLE test3 (i integer, c1 varchar(100), c2 varchar(100));
INSERT INTO test3 VALUES (4, 'hello', 'world');
INSERT INTO test3 VALUES (7, 'hello', 'world');
INSERT INTO test3 VALUES (2, 'world', 'hello');
INSERT INTO test3 VALUES (120, 'world', 'hello');

EXPLAIN ANALYZE INSERT INTO test 
SELECT *
FROM test2
WHERE test2.i NOT IN 
    (SELECT min(i) FROM test3 GROUP BY c1, c2 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);
```

Analyze prints the following:

```
                                                       QUERY PLAN                                                       
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Insert on test  (cost=15.95..55.95 rows=1200 width=4) (actual time=0.098..0.098 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on test2  (cost=15.95..55.95 rows=1200 width=4) (actual time=0.037..0.039 rows=4 loops=1)
         Filter: (NOT (hashed SubPlan 1))
         SubPlan 1
           ->  HashAggregate  (cost=13.40..15.52 rows=170 width=440) (actual time=0.017..0.018 rows=2 loops=1)
                 Filter: (count(*) > 1)
                 ->  Seq Scan on test3  (cost=0.00..11.70 rows=170 width=440) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=4 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 0.200 ms
(8 rows)
```

(The real query processes a lot more data.)

Does `loops=1` mean that PostgreSQL caches the result of the subquery? Note that the subquery works on table `test3`, therefore it's independent of the other part of the query. (Is there any other way to figure out whether PostgreSQL caches this subquery or not?)

Comment: The real query might have a different query plan. (depending on size, avalable keys/indexes, tuning, and statistics). The "loops=1" indicates that the scan is only executed once. (for nested loops, the inner loop would have to be restarted over and over again)

Answer (score 1):

No, PostgreSQL doesn't use a subquery for cache. It is able to materialize some data, but you can see it in plan. There was just only one request to subquery call.